# Beta decay of beryllium into boron: conservation of spin violated?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics

I found following reaction in my lecture:
$$^{10}Be_{6} \rightarrow ^{10}B_5+e^{-}+\overline{\nu}_e$$

since Beryllium has an even number of protons and neutrons its nuclear spin is $0$.
However, Boron has a nuclear spin of $3$, the electron $+\frac{1}{2}$ and the anti neutrino $-\frac{1}{2}$ if I am not mistaken. 

(I deduced the spins using the shell model)

I always thought that the sum of the spins should be equal on both sides or is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Doesn't charge conservation require a positron?

Comment: possibly related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/346264/spin-conservation-in-beta-decay

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spin conservation in $\beta^+$ decay](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/346264/spin-conservation-in-beta-decay)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question linked to in the comments above. This example is different because the intrinsic spins can't be coupled to make the observed spins.

Comment: Alessio can you please post a link to your lecture/course?

Comment: @magma unfortunately I am not allowed to share his lectures because of privacy policy

Comment: what is the name of the course? A link to the course website perhaps?

Comment: @magma [link](https://www.ikp.uni-koeln.de/groups/zilges/vorl/kern/kern.html) it's in german

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The intrinsic spins of all the particles are not the only angular momenta involved. If they were, then you'd be right -- it would be impossible for this decay to occur, because you can't couple spins 3, 1/2, and 1/2 to make spin 0. (The + and - signs you stated in the question don't make sense, though.)

To get this reaction to occur, we need 2 additional units of *orbital* angular momentum to be contributed by the electron and the antineutrino. This is hard to do, which is why the decay has a half-life of more than a million years.

Comment: I thought that parity would play a role but I am probably mistaken that is why I used $+\frac{1}{2}$ and $-\frac{1}{2}$ even though I am not sure if the anti neutrino has a negative sign

Comment: So you are saying that

$$^{10}Be_6 \rightarrow ^{10}B_5 + 3e^{-}  + 3\overline{\nu}_e$$ would be the correct way to write the reaction?

Comment: Parity is a separate quantum number, not a sign of the angular momentum. No, there are not 3 of each particle. The particles carry $3\hbar$ of orbital angular momentum.